# Product of Conditional Expectation of Poisson RVs

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have $(X|N=n)\sim\operatorname{Bin(n,p)}$ and $N\sim\operatorname{Poisson(\lambda)}$ with $Y=N-X$. I need to find $E[XY|N=n]$.  I know that $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson(\lambda p)}$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson(\lambda(1-p))}\implies E[XY|N=n] = E[X(N-X)|N=n]$.  Is it true that the expectation is equal to $E[NX|N=n] - E[X^2|N=n]$?  If so, is the brute force approach the only way to calculate these expectations, or is there something I'm missing here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much brute force needed.  $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally dependent
random variables for every value of $N$, but are unconditionally independent
random variables.  Also, as you say,

$$E[XY\mid N = n] = E[X(N-X)\mid N=n] = E[NX\mid N = n] -E[X^2\mid N = n]$$
But, $E[NX\mid N = n] = E[nX\mid N = n] = nE[X\mid N = n] = n(np)$ while
$$E[X^2 \mid N = n] = \operatorname{var}(X \mid N = n) + (E[X\mid N=n])^2
= np(1-p) + (np)^2$$ if you remember the standard results for the mean and
variance of a binomial random variable.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I didn't realize the N could be factored out.  I was looking at it as a random variable instead of a constant.